# Sass Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "...nth($sites, $i)": expected "}", was ": ("

Tags: css, sass

I write a sass function, and it throws an error:

```
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "...nth($sites, $i)": expected "}", was ": ("
```

my code is below:

```
@function sites-state-maps($sites, $state){
    $sites-index: 10;
    $state-index: 3;
    @for $i from 1 through $sites-index {
    @return nth($sites, $i): (
        @for $j form 1 through $state-index {
            @return nth($state, $j): state-position($j) site-position($i) @if $j < $state-index {,}
        }
    ) @if $i < $sites-index {,}
    }
    @return false;
}

$background-position: (
    sites-state-maps((aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh, ii, jj), (active, hover, current))
);
```

I have no idea what's wrong with this?

Comment: What are you expecting this to do?

Comment: I expecting it output a Maps.

Comment: You're going to have to provide the *exact* output you're expecting for that input.  This function makes no sense (and quite frankly, I wonder if you've even read anything on Sass because it looks like you're trying to follow idioms from another language).

Comment: Sass is for styling purposes.  I think you're looking for Javascript?  It looks like you're following Javascript syntax...